# Using regular expressions in field names for validation in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to use regular expression for the variable name that I'm getting in a custom request class in Laravel 5.1

What I want to achieve is, I have a `EnterBookRequest.php`. Here I accept multiple book entries at once. So I want to do something like this :

```
    public function rules()
    { 
        return [
           'book-id-*' : 'integer|min:55',
           'book-name-*' : 'string',
        ];
    }
```

Is there a **simple** way to do so? Or will I have to write it separately in the rules method.

Comment: Why can't you have a regular rule with regex pattern ?

Comment: I want to use the regex in the name of the field and not it's value. That is my  issue.

Comment: I don't think so, because the names of the fields are needed to tell the user where he did commet an input error. If the user entered a wrong value for 'book-id-5', he would receive an error message for 'book-id-5', but also for 'book-id-1', 'book-id-2', 'book-id-3', etc.